# How can I change the "Frequently Used" emoji in Discord?

Tags: discord

When I click on Discord's emoji button, there is a section for "Frequently Used". Unfortunately, it contains a bunch of useless emoji I've never used like  and .

I want to change it to the emoji I actually use. For instance, I often type in `thumb` in the search and select the , but despite doing that a few dozen times, it doesn't show up in the "Frequently Used" list.

I've looked through the preferences and haven't found a way to change this. How can I change the "Frequently Used" emoji group?

Comment: [Meta Discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12989/28182) relevant to this question.

Comment: You do say you have never used those emojis, but have you ever used them in reactions to posts? In my own experiences, it feels like Discord likes to prioritize emotes being used as reactions for my favorite tab over emojis I actually type in chats. That includes posts that require you to react to them for roles or polls.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a little complicated.

Firstly, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (Windows/Linux) or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (Mac), and go to `Application` tab (you might need to press the >> button). Click on Local Storage from left bar, and pick the discordapp.com result:

[image: Local Storage display on chrome dev tools]

On the right bar, find "EmojiUsageHistory" Key, and copy the Value of it (right click on value, pick edit, copy it. As there's a lot of stuff in there, it might take some time)

As an example for this post, I'll remove the smirk_cat emoji (bottom row, fourth from right):

[image: Emoji picker of discord]

Paste the "EmojiUsageHistory" values you copied to your favorite text editor, and search for the emoji's name (or the snowflake, if it's a custom emoji. To find the snowflake of a custom emoji, write `\:name of emoji:`, the number is the snowflake of emoji), should look like this:

[image: a part of the EmojiUsageHistory that we are editing]

Remove the parts until the next emoji, ensure that a `,` is between the previous and the next emoji.

If you want to make sure that an emoji you want shows up on the list, find it and change `totalUses`, `frecency` and `score` to a high value (like 500).

[image: Result of EmojiUsageHistory]

Copy that text, edit the value of "EmojiUsageHistory" again and paste the values.

Restart discord by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (Windows/Linux) or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (Mac), the emoji will be gone from the list:

[image: Emoji picker with the unwanted emoji removed]

Comment: Just to add to above, for Windows/Linux, press Ctrl+Shift+I

Comment: @Jason thanks, corrected.

Comment: It's now stored in the `EmojiStore` key with an embedded `UsageHistory` property.